# Find distinct value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this :

```
DH_doc_number   DH_by_default   DH_reference    DH_your_ref DH_our_ref
OF-82-YC         1          
OF-82-YC         1               dfwf   
OF-78-YC         0
```

there can be only one distinct dh_doc_number which can have "1" default value.
Here it's "OF-82-YC". So the other dh_doc_value " OF-78-YC" cant be "1" too.

How can I query this in t-sql to know if there are more than 2 distinct value which has in dh_by_default the value 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct DH_doc_number)
from t
where DH_by_default = 1;
```

This returns the number of `DH_doc_number` that have the default set.